# Combining multiple bash parameter substitutions within same variable set line without using any other commands

Tags: bash, variables, parameters, concatenation, substitution

Example of what I want to combine:

```
sVar=$(whoami)
sVar=${sVar^}
sVar=${sVar::1}
```

Output:

- Uppercase first character of username

Requirements:

- One-liner
- Do the rest of the processing with parameter substitutions except for the initial command substitution above $(whoami)

I realize this can be done with tr, sed, awk, printf, cut, etc.; but that is not the point of the question.

Any help is appreciate!

This isn't the real code or anything indicative of what I am wanting to actually do.  I will often default (or try to) to using just one command over concatenating multiple commands.

I've seen other posts state that concatenating within the braces are not possible, but I know that everything is possible.

Please don't:

- Reference other posts as duplicate that say it's impossible

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to do multiple parameter substitutions in a single command. Why do you have such eggregious requirements?

Comment: Does it count as a one-liner if you do multiple commands separated by `;` on the same line?

Comment: `sVar=$(whoami); sVar=${sVar^}; sVar=${sVar::1}`

Comment: If you are going to post something like this, it deserves a bounty.  Even if it's possible, it's not something that should be done, so it's an academic test.

Comment: @cyrus: You can leave out the semicolons. A command can contain multiple variable assignments and they are performed left to right ("from the beginning of the command text to the end", as Posix says.)

Comment: `sVar=$(whoami) && sVar=${sVar^} && sVar=${sVar::1}`

Comment: A question predicated on a false premise ("everything is possible") and a knowing decision to discard expert advice and knowledge when that doesn't match one's preconceived notions certainly falls under the rubric of "not useful". Telling others *not* to close something as duplicate when it *is* in fact duplicative, moreover, is asserting a level of authority one does not possess.

Answer (score 5):

One liner:

```
sVar=$(whoami) sVar=${sVar^} sVar=${sVar::1}
```

It may not be what you were looking for, but it is certainly a single command and uses parameter substitutions. A single command can consist of multiple variable assignments, in which case they are performed left to right.

The subject of a parameter substitution is a variable name, an indirection (a <kbd>!</kbd> followed by a variable name), or a subscript expression (a variable name -- not an indirection -- followed by a subscript within <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>. That's a bit limited, to be sure, but that's bash. (Posix shell is even more restrictive; it has no indirection nor arrays, and fewer types of expansion.)

---

Posix wording from XCU, emphasis added:

> When a given simple command is required to be executed… the following expansions, assignments, and redirections shall all be performed *from the beginning of the command text to the end*:
>
> …
>
> 4. Each variable assignment shall be expanded for tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal *prior to assigning the value*.